# CPU overheating while reading file in Java with TimerTask

Tags: java, swing, file, bufferedreader, timertask

I'm making a sort of IOT simulator development kit. To continuously update my devices' status (saved in different files) I've created a TimerTask with a refresh rate of 10 ms that continuously read a string. That's the code:

```
public void update() throws IOException {
        File f = new File("ClaireSDK/sensor/"+id+".sensor");
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
                    String line = s.next();
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,";;;");
                    id = st.nextToken();
                    isTurnedOn = Boolean.valueOf(st.nextToken());
                    input = st.nextToken();
                    output = st.nextToken();
                    if(isTurnedOn) {
                        switchButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker());
                        switchButton.setText("ON");
                    }
                    else {
                        switchButton.setForeground(Color.RED.darker());
                        switchButton.setText("OFF");
                    }
                    updateGui();
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    s.close();
                } catch (Exception err) {

                }
            }

        }, 0, refreshRate);
    }
```

I tried with `BufferedReader` but same results. UpdateGUI method refresh a `JTextField` that prints the device's status. Anyway, adding three or four device to my simulation, my CPU and GPU reaches temperatures like 101C° and my fan speed up very fast. (I'm on a MacBook Pro).

[image]

What I should do to improve my code?

Comment: Either your cooler broke, or the code is CPU-hugging. What happens if you increase the time between update runs? If that fixes the issue, you could consider scheduling the next update run after a fixed amount of time, at the end of the update function, rather than scheduling at a fixed rate. That way, if the update function takes longer than expected, there is still idle time.

Comment: What is the "0" for?  Seems to me like that is a little low.

Comment: As you are using `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate` if your task takes longer than your `refreshRate` essentially you will be running the task non stop. Try using `Timer#schedule` instead. Also you should do all changes to the gui on the Swing EDT thread.

Comment: Hey! Thanks to all! I solved the problem by using Timer.schedule() instead of scheduleAtFixedRate, invokelater for GUI update and 50ms as refresh. 0 means that my timer will never stop automatically